# If $|G|=30$ and $P_3$, $P_5$ are $3$- and $5$-Sylow subgroups respectively, then one of them is normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, alternative-proof, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

l've already read (and understood) [a different way](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1402245/show-that-if-g-30-then-g-has-normal-3-sylow-and-5-sylow-subgroups) to solve this problem, but I wanted to know if there's any way the following idea could work:

Let's assume $P_3P_5$ is a subgroup, then its order should be $3\cdot 5=15$. Therefore, its index would be $2$, so we could conclude it's a normal subgroup. The problem is, $P_3P_5$ would only be a subgroup if either $P_3$ or $P_5$ are normal, so I'm not sure any of this was useful.

Is there any way we can turn this into a working argument?

Comment: I don't think it helps but you seem to misunderstand the condition for $XY$ to be a subgroup: $X$ or $Y$ normal is sufficient but is not necessary. The correct criterion is that $XY=YX$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician But… if either $X$ or $Y$ is normal, then $XY=YX$ would be normal too, right…?

Comment: Oh okay, I think I see what you mean. Then maybe I could use that $P_3P_5=P_5P_3$, which seems easy to prove. I mean, if $x \in P_3$ and $y \in P_5$, $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ would be contained in their intersection, which is ${1}$…

Comment: I don't see how the commutator lies in the intersection without Normality, which would make the whole argument circular.

Comment: I cannot see how to make this approach work, but there is a nice elementary proof of the more general result that groups $G$ of order $2n$ with $n$ odd have a subgroup of order $n$. You use Cayley's Theorem to define a homomorphism $\phi:G \to S_{2n}$, observe that, for elements $g \in G$ of order $2$, $\phi(g)$ is an odd permutation, and then take the inverse image under $\phi$ of $\phi(G) \cap A_{2n}$ as your normal subgroup

Comment: If $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$, then the set $HK=\{hk\mid h\in H,k\in K\}$ is a subgroup if and only if $HK=KH$ as sets. This holds if either $H$ or $K$ are normal in $G$ (or if $K$ normalizes $H$ or if $H$ normalizes $K$). However, even if $H$ is normal, you cannot in general conclude that $HK$ will be normal (unless you know $K$ Is normal too). It could be normal, or it could fail to be normal. For instance, $G=S_3\times S_3$, $H=S_3\times\{e\}$, $K=\{e\}\times\langle(12)\rangle$ has $HK$ not normal.